# how can I replace 2 dim array?

Tags: c#

I want to replace array elements

```
arr1[n][m] to arr2[m][n]
```

ex:

```
arr1[0]{a1,a2,a3}
arr1[1]{b1,b2,b3}
```

change to:

```
arr2[0]{a1,b1}
arr2[1]{a2,b2}
arr2[2]{a3,b3}
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to transpose a matrix? That is not what you have written but...

Comment: Post your code in the question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It seems like you want to transpose the array, but even that much is not entirely clear. The only thing that is clear is that if you bothered to make any attempt on your own to write the code you want, you did not include any evidence of that in your question. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, and even if we assume you want to transpose the array, your question is too vague to know exactly the best approach in your scenario would be. Please fix the question so it includes a good [mcve], explain what that code does and what you want instead, and what specifically you need help with.

Comment: I guess this is going to receive at least 1x downvotes before being deleted, even after closed it still can receive downvotes. You'd better improve it by adding some code of your own to show the effort you have had so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to do the transpose of a given matrix.

```
public T[,] TransposeMatrix(T[,] matrix)
{
    var rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
    var columns = matrix.GetLength(1);
    var result = new T[columns, rows];

    for (var c = 0; c < columns; ++c)
    {
        for (var r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
        {
            result[c, r] = matrix[r, c];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```